# RewriteOptions Inherit don't work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, inheritance

**main folder .htaccess**

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=mktoken:123456]
```

**sub folder .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !mktoken=%{ENV:mktoken};? [NC]
#RewriteRule .* - [E=mktoken:123456]
RewriteRule .* /acompanha/index.php?mktoken=%{ENV:mktoken} [L,R]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,F]
```

if i uncomment the rule in sub folder .htaccess the mktoken env is set properly. But not Inherit from main folder .htaccess, why?

The idea is create some type of global var do block access from cookie.

Any Help?

Comment: If you are using Apache 2.3.10 and up, what you're looking for is `RewriteOptions InheritBefore` or even better, probably `RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore` ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `RewriteOptions Inherit` only includes directives from parent `.htaccess` **after** all the directives of current .htaccess.

As per [official Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions):

> Rules inherited from the **parent scope are applied after rules specified in the child scope**.

You will need to set env variable in child score again since your rewrite rules are depending on that value.

Comment: Ok, but this don't work for me i will have +1000 sub folders, the trick is set only on one file!

Comment: Unfortunately that is how htaccess works but if you upgrade your Apache then there are few options available.